# Derivation of Dirac equation using the Lagrangian density for Dirac field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, dirac-equation, variational-calculus

How can I derive the Dirac equation from the Lagrangian density for the Dirac field?

Comment: Use the Euler-Lagarange equation for fields.

Comment: This standard derivation is done in every QFT text. If you are getting stuck can you please elaborate about what exactly is giving you trouble?

Comment: Yeah, it's like a 2-line derivation

Answer (score 19):

The Lagrangian density for a Dirac field is
$$
\mathcal{L} = i\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi -m \bar\psi\psi
$$
The Euler-Lagrange equation reads
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\psi} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\right] = 0
$$
We treat $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$ as independent dynamical variables. In fact, it is easier to consider the Euler-Lagrange for $\bar\psi$
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\bar\psi} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\bar\psi)}\right] = 0\\
\Rightarrow i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi -m\psi - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}[ 0] = 0\\
\Rightarrow i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi -m\psi=0
$$
The partial differentiation is trivial - remember that $\bar\psi$ and $\partial_\mu\bar\psi$ are treated as though independent. We recover the Dirac equation as expected. If we had instead chosen the Euler-Lagrange for $\psi$, we would have found the conjugate Dirac equation.

Comment: While treating $\psi$ and $\bar{psi}$ as distinct, are we also accepting that the Lagrangian is of a interacting theory?

Comment: The differentiation is actually *not* trivial unless you are already aware that the components of $\psi$ are grassman variables. This means to take the (right-handed) derivative of one of the components, you have to commute it to the right first. In this case, we are lucky and the Equation of Motion is the same anyway, because both terms are just multiplied by $(-1)$ and the RHS is $0$ anywa. However, $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \bar{\psi}}$ is actually $(-1)$ times the result you wrote down. Just a subtlety that may be important for some readers. Also, note that the EOM is defined component-wise.

Comment: @innisfree why did you consider $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ as independent variables?

Comment: @innisfree I’m also always confused about this. Why declare $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ to be independent? They clearly aren’t independent in the usual sense.

Comment: You can do the calculation without the independence cheat.  With some effort you can show that $\delta \mathcal{L}=\mathcal{E} \delta \psi + \mathcal{E}^* \delta \psi^*+\textrm{total derivative}$, where $\mathcal{E}=0$ is the form of the dirac equation you get from the Euler-Lagrange equations for $\psi$, treating $\bar{\psi}$ as independent.  Then you choose a variation with $\delta \psi^*=\delta \psi$ and conclude $\mathcal{E}=-\mathcal{E}^*$.  Next choose a variation with $\delta \psi^*=-\delta \psi$ and conclude $\mathcal{E}=+\mathcal{E}^*$.  Thus $\mathcal{E}=0$, the Dirac equation.