# Deriving adjoint Dirac equation from Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, wavefunction, dirac-equation, complex-numbers

I'm trying to derive the adjoint Dirac equation from the Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi-m\bar{\psi}\psi$$

To start, I plugged it into the Euler-Lagrange equation with my variation variable being $\psi$:

$$\partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\right)-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\psi}=0$$

Which yields:

$$\partial_\mu(i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu)-m\bar{\psi}=0$$

Next, I factored out the $i$, then used the anticommutation relation $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}$ to swap $\gamma^0$ (from the adjoint wavefunction) and $\gamma^\mu$. However, when I do this I don't get something resembling the Dirac adjoint; I have an extra $2\partial_\mu\psi^\dagger$ term, so I must have done something wrong (I end up getting $2\partial_\mu\psi^\dagger-\partial_\mu(\psi^\dagger\gamma^\mu\gamma^0)-m\bar{\psi}=0$). Could I just have a pointer in the right direction; I'm unsure how to proceed from what I have from the Euler-Lagrange equation to $\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m)=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to derive the equation of motion for $\bar \psi$, then you already have it. It's commonly written as

$$\bar \psi \left(i\gamma^\mu \overleftarrow{\partial}_\mu+m\right)=0$$

Where it's understood that we should act with the derivative on $\bar\psi$ as normal, i.e. $\partial_\mu \bar \psi$, but that the $\gamma^\mu$ must still multiply on the right.

Comment: I understand that's the equation, but how do I get from $\partial_\mu (i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu)-m\bar{\psi}=0$ to the equation you wrote. Does the derivative going to the right also conjugate $i$?

Comment: @moboDawn_φ well your second term in the equation of motion $-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi}$ is off by a minus sign. Also your Lagrangian appears to be missing a factor of $i$ in the first term.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, that was a stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: @moboDawn_φ not stupid, just a small mistake. Happens all the time. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out to me!

Answer (score 0):

With all the constants made explicit...
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}
&= iħ \bar{ψ} γ^μ ∂_μ ψ - mc \bar{ψ} ψ\\
Δ\mathcal{L}
&= iħ Δ\bar{ψ} γ^μ ∂_μ ψ + iħ \bar{ψ} γ^μ ∂_μ Δψ - mc Δ\bar{ψ} ψ - mc \bar{ψ} Δψ\\
&= iħ Δ\bar{ψ} γ^μ ∂_μ ψ + \left(∂_μ (iħ \bar{ψ} γ^μ Δψ) - iħ ∂_μ\bar{ψ} γ^μ Δψ\right) - mc Δ\bar{ψ} ψ - mc \bar{ψ} Δψ\\
&= Δ\bar{ψ} \left(iħ γ^μ ∂_μ ψ - mc ψ\right) - \left(iħ ∂_μ\bar{ψ} γ^μ + mc \bar{ψ}\right) Δψ + ∂_μ \left(iħ \bar{ψ} γ^μ Δψ\right)\\
&⇒ iħ γ^μ ∂_μ ψ - mc ψ = 0, \quad iħ ∂_μ\bar{ψ} γ^μ + mc \bar{ψ} = 0, \quad Δ\mathcal{L} ≡ ∂_μ \left(iħ \bar{ψ} γ^μ Δψ\right)
\end{align}$$
where "≡" denotes "on-shell" equality, with $Δ\mathcal{L}$ reduced, on-shell, to the variational involving the involving the boundary term.

It should actually be made symmetric so that the boundary term gets contributions from $Δ\bar{ψ}$ as well as from $Δψ$:
$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{ψ} \left(iħ \overleftrightarrow{γ^μ ∂_μ} - mc\right) ψ,$$
where
$$\overleftrightarrow{γ^μ ∂_μ} = \frac{γ^μ \overrightarrow{∂_μ} - \overleftarrow{∂_μ} γ^μ}{2}.$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}
&= \frac{1}{2}\overbrace{\bar{ψ} \left(iħ γ^μ \overrightarrow{∂_μ} - mc\right) ψ}^{\overrightarrow{\mathcal{L}}} - \frac{1}{2}\overbrace{\bar{ψ} \left(iħ \overleftarrow{∂_μ} γ^μ + mc\right) ψ}^{\overleftarrow{\mathcal{L}}}\\
Δ\overrightarrow{\mathcal{L}}
&= Δ\left(\bar{ψ}\left(iħ γ^μ \overrightarrow{∂_μ} - mc\right) ψ\right)\\
&= Δ\bar{ψ} \left(iħ γ^μ \overrightarrow{∂_μ} - mc\right) ψ - \bar{ψ}\left(iħ \overleftarrow{∂_μ} γ^μ + mc\right) Δψ + ∂_μ \left(iħ \bar{ψ} γ^μ Δψ\right)\\
Δ\overleftarrow{\mathcal{L}}
&=Δ\left(\bar{ψ}\left(iħ \overleftarrow{∂_μ} γ^μ + mc\right) ψ\right)\\
&= \bar{ψ}\left(iħ \overleftarrow{∂_μ} γ^μ + mc\right) Δψ - Δ\bar{ψ} \left(iħ γ^μ \overrightarrow{∂_μ} - mc\right) ψ + ∂_μ \left(iħ Δ\bar{ψ} γ^μ ψ\right)\\
&⇒\\
Δ\mathcal{L}
&= Δ\bar{ψ} \left(iħ γ^μ \overrightarrow{∂_μ} - mc\right) ψ - \bar{ψ}\left(iħ \overleftarrow{∂_μ} γ^μ + mc\right) Δψ + ∂_μ \left(iħ \frac{\bar{ψ} γ^μ Δψ - Δ\bar{ψ} γ^μ ψ}{2}\right)
\end{align}.$$

Defining
$$\overleftrightarrow{γ^μ Δ} = \frac{γ^μ \overrightarrow{Δ} - \overleftarrow{Δ} γ^μ}{2},$$
the boundary term can be written:
$$∂_μ \left(\bar{ψ} iħ\overleftrightarrow{γ^μ Δ} ψ\right).$$
Then,
$$
Δ\mathcal{L}
= Δ\bar{ψ} \left(iħ γ^μ \overrightarrow{∂_μ} - mc\right) ψ - \bar{ψ}\left(iħ \overleftarrow{∂_μ} γ^μ + mc\right) Δψ + ∂_μ \left(\bar{ψ} iħ\overleftrightarrow{γ^μ Δ} ψ\right).
$$